# how to localize an xml based file in java?

Tags: java, xml, localization, internationalization

Say I have a drop-down menu in my java application. I used the below XML code to call the list of menus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<menutypes>
    <Menutype>
        <name>Menu A</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <param>0</param>
        <diameter>0</diameter>
        <autocollimatable>false</autocollimatable>
        <autotrackable>false</autotrackable>
    </Menutype>
    <Menutype>
        <name>Menu B</name>
        <type>1</type>
        <param>0</param>
        <diameter>30</diameter>
        <autocollimatable>true</autocollimatable>
        <autotrackable>false</autotrackable>
    </Menutype>
    <Menutype>
        <name>Menu C</name>
        <type>0</type>
        <param>-17</param>
        <diameter>23</diameter>
        <autocollimatable>true</autocollimatable>
        <autotrackable>false</autotrackable>
    </Menutype>
</menutypes>
```

Now I call the above menus in one of my java class like so; `instance = JAXB.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("src/resource/menutypes.xml"), Menutypes.class);`. Now I want to implement localization for each corresponding *menus* based on the user's locale settings like one for Japanese and one for Chinese and so on so that when they open the app, it will show the language based on their locale. Is there any effective way to implement this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to have a `ResourceBundle` that specifies that name of the XML file to use for each locale, and then get the filename from it. You would then have one XML file per locale.

**MenuBundle_en_US.properties**

```
filename=menutypes_en_US.xml
```

**MenuBundle_jp_JP.properties**

```
filename=menutypes_jp_JP.xml
```

**MenuBundle_zh_CN.properties**

```
filename=menutypes_zh_CN.xml
```

**Menu.java**

```
public Menutypes loadMenus(Locale locale) {
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MenuBundle", locale);
    String filename = bundle.getString("filename");
    Menutypes instance = JAXB.unmarshal
        new FileInputStream("src/resource/" + filename), Menutypes.class);
    return instance;
}
```

Something like that, modulo error handling. I don't know if there's a better way to do it with XML.

Comment: I understand the `ResourceBundle` and a separate XML for each locale. But if I have below codes, how would you suggest to integrate your answer? 
`private static Menutypes instance;
    public static Menutypes getInstance() {
     if (instance == null) {
      instance = new Menutypes();          
            try {
                instance = JAXB.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("menutypes.xml"), Menutypes.class);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {             
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
        return instance;
    }`

Comment: @akatsuki You would get the filename from the ResourceBundle and open that instead of `menutypes.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample.

```
public final class ResourceUtils {
    private static final String MESSAGE_FILE_NAME = "messages";
    public static String getMessage(String key) {
        Locale local = SessionPreferences.getCurrentLocale();
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(MESSAGE_FILE_NAME, local);
        return bundle.getString(key);
    }
}
```

The file messages.properties

```
APP.title=HOME
APP.home.title=Salesman
```

Then you can modify the set/get:

```
class Menutypes {
    String getName() {
        return ResourceUtils.getMessage('APP.title');
    }
}
```